# Difficulty in using value set argument. Code below

Tags: c

I have the following code snippet: Basically I am trying to get the value from extract function using value set method. Following is the snippet below

```
int extract(uint8_t *msg) 
{
    msg = get_value();
    print(msg); // I am able to print the value here.
}


int main()
{
     uint8_t msg;
     extract(&msg);
     print(msg)   // Here it is printing incorrect value..
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine all the answers given, you might get something working.

There's a number of errors in your code and it is unclear what is returned by `get_value()` and what is the parameter required to `print()`. 
My guess is your `print()` function takes a pointer - that's why `print()` works in `extract()` - and you should also pass the msg pointer by reference for it to work in main. So you might need something like this (C code):

```
int extract(uint8_t **msg) 
{
    (*msg) = get_value();
    print(*msg);
}


int main()
{
     uint8_t *msg;
     extract(&msg);
     print(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing msg as a pointer.

```
int extract(uint8_t *msg) 
{
    msg = get_value();
    print(msg); // I am able to print the value here.
}
```

should be

```
int extract(uint8_t *msg) 
{
    *msg = get_value();
    print(*msg);
}
```

Comment: error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
Is the error I am seeing

Comment: It returns *some* a pointer to some structure which I am going to be typecasting and using with the help of msg pointer

Comment: Then it sould be msg = get_value(); , but there is no way to know that from your question

Answer (score 0):

msg = get_value() assigns a value to a pointer. You should use  *msg = get_value() to assign value to variable msg defined in main.